# Time (only) class

Tags: c++, datetime

Working in C++ and I have some code which I'm refactoring.  I have some code that needs to work with times of day but not dates.  I do some juggling with `time_t` and `struct tm` but it's a pain and not intuitive to use.  So I decided to make a basic time class with no date component.  Let me know if you see any issues or have ideas for improvement:

TimeOnly.h

```
#pragma once

class TimeOnly
{
public:
    TimeOnly(int hour, int minute, int second);
    virtual ~TimeOnly();

    static TimeOnly GetCurrentTime();
    virtual int GetHour() const;
    virtual int GetMinute() const;
    virtual int GetSecond() const;

private:
    int hour_;
    int minute_;
    int second_;

};

inline bool operator==(const TimeOnly& lhs, const TimeOnly& rhs)
{
    /* do actual comparison */
    return (
        (lhs.GetHour() == rhs.GetHour())
        && (lhs.GetMinute() == rhs.GetMinute())
        && (lhs.GetSecond() == rhs.GetSecond())
        );
} 

inline bool operator!=(const TimeOnly& lhs, const TimeOnly& rhs){ return !operator==(lhs, rhs); } 
inline bool operator<(const TimeOnly& lhs, const TimeOnly& rhs)
{ 
    /* do actual comparison */ 
    if(lhs.GetHour() >= rhs.GetHour())
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if(lhs.GetMinute() >= rhs.GetMinute())
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if(lhs.GetSecond() >= rhs.GetSecond())
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
} 

inline bool operator>(const TimeOnly& lhs, const TimeOnly& rhs){ return operator<(rhs, lhs); } 
inline bool operator<=(const TimeOnly& lhs, const TimeOnly& rhs){ return !operator>(lhs, rhs); } 
inline bool operator>=(const TimeOnly& lhs, const TimeOnly& rhs){ return !operator<(lhs, rhs); }
```

TimeOnly.cpp

```
#include "TimeOnly.h"
#include <stdexcept>
#include <ctime>

TimeOnly::TimeOnly(int hour, int minute, int second):
    hour_(hour),
    minute_(minute),
    second_(second)
{
    if(
        (hour_ >= 0 && hour_ <= 23)
        && (minute_ >= 0 && minute_ <= 59)
        && (second_ >= 0 && second_ <= 59)
        )
    {
        //ok
    }
    else
    {
        throw std::invalid_argument("Time must be between 0:00:00 and 23:59:59");
    }
}

TimeOnly TimeOnly::GetCurrentTime()
{
    // get time now
    time_t t = time(0);
    struct tm * now = localtime(&t);
    return TimeOnly(now->tm_hour, now->tm_min, now->tm_sec);
}

TimeOnly::~TimeOnly()
{
}


int TimeOnly::GetHour() const
{
    return hour_;
}

int TimeOnly::GetMinute() const
{
    return minute_;
}

int TimeOnly::GetSecond() const
{
    return second_;
}
```

**Edit**

This is my revised class taking some suggestions from the answers:

Time.h

```
#pragma once

class TimeOnly
{
public:
    TimeOnly(int seconds);
    TimeOnly(int hour, int minute, int second);
    ~TimeOnly();

    TimeOnly AddSeconds(int seconds);
    static TimeOnly Now();
    int GetHour() const;
    int GetMinute() const;
    int GetSecond() const;
    int GetTotalSeconds() const;

private:
    void Init(int seconds);
    int secondsInDay_;

    static const int SECONDS_IN_A_DAY = 86400;
    static const int SECONDS_IN_AN_HOUR = 3600;
    static const int SECONDS_IN_A_MINUTE = 60;
};

inline bool operator==(const TimeOnly& lhs, const TimeOnly& rhs)
{
    /* do actual comparison */
    return lhs.GetTotalSeconds() == rhs.GetTotalSeconds();
} 

inline bool operator!=(const TimeOnly& lhs, const TimeOnly& rhs){ return !operator==(lhs, rhs); } 
inline bool operator<(const TimeOnly& lhs, const TimeOnly& rhs)
{ 
    /* do actual comparison */ 
    return lhs.GetTotalSeconds() < rhs.GetTotalSeconds();
} 

inline bool operator>(const TimeOnly& lhs, const TimeOnly& rhs){ return operator<(rhs, lhs); } 
inline bool operator<=(const TimeOnly& lhs, const TimeOnly& rhs){ return !operator>(lhs, rhs); } 
inline bool operator>=(const TimeOnly& lhs, const TimeOnly& rhs){ return !operator<(lhs, rhs); }
```

TimeOnly.cpp

```
#include "TimeOnly.h"
#include <stdexcept>
#include <ctime>

TimeOnly::TimeOnly(int seconds)
{
    Init(seconds);
}

TimeOnly::TimeOnly(int hour, int minute, int second)
{
    int seconds = (hour * SECONDS_IN_AN_HOUR) + (minute * SECONDS_IN_A_MINUTE) + seconds;
    Init(seconds);
}


TimeOnly::~TimeOnly()
{
}

void TimeOnly::Init(int seconds)
{
    if(seconds >= 0 && seconds < SECONDS_IN_A_DAY)
    {
        secondsInDay_ = seconds;
    }
    else
    {
        throw std::invalid_argument("Time must be between 0:00:00 and 23:59:59");
    }
}


TimeOnly TimeOnly::AddSeconds(int seconds)
{
    int newSeconds = (secondsInDay_ + seconds) % SECONDS_IN_A_DAY;
    return TimeOnly(newSeconds);
}


TimeOnly TimeOnly::Now()
{
    // get time now
    time_t t = time(0);
    struct tm * now = localtime( & t );
    return TimeOnly(now->tm_hour, now->tm_min, now->tm_sec);
}


int TimeOnly::GetHour() const
{
    return secondsInDay_ / SECONDS_IN_AN_HOUR;
}

int TimeOnly::GetMinute() const
{
    return (secondsInDay_ % (SECONDS_IN_AN_HOUR)) / SECONDS_IN_A_MINUTE;
}

int TimeOnly::GetSecond() const
{
    return secondsInDay_ % SECONDS_IN_A_MINUTE;
}

int TimeOnly::GetTotalSeconds() const
{
    return secondsInDay_;
}
```

(Note renamed `GetCurrentTime()` to `Now()` because I was getting `error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol... GetTickCount(void)` even though I have no `GetTickCount` method.  Turns out winbase.h has `#define GetCurrentTime() GetTickCount()`)

Comment: Why not call it TimeSpan which is the time span since last midnight. This has got to be a solved problem. For instance, see this document for inspiration http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx

Comment: To me, a TimeSpan is conceptually something different.  Yes I see how you could use it the same but it also allows arbitrarily large TimeSpans whereas I'm looking for time of day in the 24 range of a day.  If it is solved elsewhere I'm all ears.  Good idea, however, for looking at TimeSpan for additional methods to add.

Comment: I will look for the C++ implementations. Looks to me like TimeOnly can wrap (contain) a general TimeSpan and add a few restrictions.

Comment: I serached online using http://www.koders.com/default.aspx?s=TimeSpan+GetMinute&submit=Search&la=Cpp&li=* (the google code search alternative), and found something like this: http://www.koders.com/cpp/fid8469F6817E47596C30815ECCC492260ACA125DC5.aspx?s=TimeSpan+GetMinute#L22

Comment: Same with https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=TimeSpan&repo=&langOverride=&start_value=1&type=Code&language=C%2B%2B search: https://github.com/DrFrankenstein/amnlib/blob/397a304961e330659bc70418d88b4476d2f90013/timespan.cpp  https://github.com/riviera/plex/blob/db3dd2dd7d87c16901cbdc4a964596f305e3f9b9/xbmc/DateTime.cpp

Comment: I agree with OP, a time span is to time as `ptrdiff_t` is to a pointer. They are conceptually different. .NET makes the same distinction, by the way (but in .NET a time always has a date associated).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Personally I would look at boost. They probably have something.

#### Comments:

```
virtual ~TimeOnly();
```

Are you really going to derive from this class?

#### Implementation

```
private:
    int hour_;
    int minute_;
    int second_;
```

Holding these as separate fields makes the rest of the code more complex.
I personally would hold this a single value (seconds since start of day).

Then all your comparisons become trivial.
Your get functions become slightly more complex but not not very much:

```
private:
   int secondsInDay;

inline bool TimeOnly::equal(const TimeOnly& rhs)
{
    return secondsInDay == rhs.secondsInDay;
} 

inline bool TimeOnly::less(const TimeOnly& rhs)
{ 
    return secondsInDay < rhs.secondsInDay;
} 

int TimeOnly::GetHour() const
{
    return secondsInDay / (60 * 60);
}

int TimeOnly::GetMinute() const
{
    return (secondsInDay % (60 * 60)) / 60;
}

int TimeOnly::GetSecond() const
{
    return secondsInDay % 60;
}

inline bool operator==(const TimeOnly& lhs, const TimeOnly& rhs) {return lhs.equal(rhs);} 
inline bool operator!=(const TimeOnly& lhs, const TimeOnly& rhs) {return !lhs == rhs); } 
inline bool operator< (const TimeOnly& lhs, const TimeOnly& rhs) {return lhs.less(rhs);} 
inline bool operator> (const TimeOnly& lhs, const TimeOnly& rhs) {return  (rhs < lhs); } 
inline bool operator<=(const TimeOnly& lhs, const TimeOnly& rhs) {return !(lhs > rhs); } 
inline bool operator>=(const TimeOnly& lhs, const TimeOnly& rhs) {return !(lhs < rhs); }
```

Comment: I looked at [Boost.Date_Time](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/date_time.html) but as far as I can tell there will always be a date associated.  I guess I could use boost's time_duration as the underlying implementation to my class.  Probably cleaner, but I thought the class was pretty simple to begin with.  Good idea with the seconds of the day.

Comment: Good point about the virtual, you're right this will probably be a "leaf" class.  Actually I realized I'll probably need at least an `AddSeconds()` method, and this is where your data representation really shines, then it's just adding x number of seconds (and modding by the number of seconds in a day to handle the wrap around).

Comment: In your comparison operator definitions, can I access private members even though the operator definitions are non-member functions?

Comment: Yes. Because they are the same class you can access private members of other instances. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/437507/14065

Comment: But these are non-member operator definitions, do they need to be declared `friend` for that to work?

Comment: @User: Whoops. OK refactored slightly.

Answer (score 2):

Nicer to split this into a new method (can be reused.)

```
bool TimeOnly::isVallid(int h, int m, int s) {
    return ((hour_ >= 0 && hour_ <= 23)
     && (minute_ >= 0 && minute_ <= 59)
     && (second_ >= 0 || second_ <= 59)
     );
}
```

Generally nicer to check validity first in the condition rather than in else.

```
TimeOnly::TimeOnly(int hour, int minute, int second):
    hour_(hour),
    minute_(minute),
    second_(second)
{
    if(!isValid(hour,minute,second))
        throw std::invalid_argument("Time must be between 0:00:00 and 23:59:59");
}
```

Think how you would like to keep the seconds minutes hours, Keeping it as seconds as in previous comment is a valid option. Another that does not require you to recompute it but will still simplify your code is to keep it as an array of 3 and index it by enum. Note that it can be extended easily for date, month year too.

```
enum Time_t
{
    Sec,
    Min,
    Hour
}
```

You can also use this for your accessors.

```
int TimeOnly::GetTime(Time_t t) const
{
    return time_[t];
}
```

This pays off in comparison operators.

```
inline bool operator==(const TimeOnly& lhs, const TimeOnly& rhs)
{
    /* do actual comparison */
    for(Time_t t = Hour; t >= Sec; t = static_cast<Time_t>(t-1))
       if(lhs.GetTime(t) != rhs.GetTime(t)) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Or you could use the STL to lexicographically compare both. (The operator becomes a friend.)

```
bool cmp(int i, int j) {
  return i < j;
}

bool operator<(const TimeOnly& lhs, const TimeOnly& rhs)
{
  return lexicographical_compare(lhs.time_, lhs.time_+3, rhs.time_, rhs.time_+3, cmp);
}
```

Correspondingly the equality is just

```
bool operator==(const TimeOnly& lhs, const TimeOnly& rhs)
{
  return equal(lhs.time_, lhs.time_ +3, rhs.time_);
}
```

This does not look right.

```
inline bool operator>(const TimeOnly& lhs, const TimeOnly& rhs){ return operator<(rhs, lhs); }
```

You can directly use the operator rather than use the function syntax.

```
inline bool operator!=(const TimeOnly& lhs, const TimeOnly& rhs){return !(lhs == rhs);} 
inline bool operator>(const TimeOnly& lhs, const TimeOnly& rhs){return !((lhs < rhs) || (lhs == rhs));} 
inline bool operator<=(const TimeOnly& lhs, const TimeOnly& rhs){return !(lhs > rhs);} 
inline bool operator>=(const TimeOnly& lhs, const TimeOnly& rhs){return !(lhs < rhs); }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I like the idea of packaging the validation check into an `IsValid` function.  Realistically I don't think I'd call it anywhere else but it does improve the readability of the code.  Using an array with an enum and for loops is interesting but it does not seem clearer/easier to me so I don't think I'd make that change.  As for using the operator directly rather than the function syntax in the operator definitions, I'm not sure, I just cut and pasted the code from this [Operator overloading](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4421719/155268) question on stackoverflow.

Comment: Well, The problem is really that of lexicographically ordering a 3-tuple. So I felt it didn't make sense to unroll it. The bonus is that lex-compare is in STL so we can take advantage of that. See my updated version.

Answer (score 2):

Your (modified) solution looks decent. My only noteworthy comments would be to use `unsigned` instead of `int` (where appropriate); and, to modify it slightly to not have the '1 day only' restriction.

However, I would recommend that you use `std::chrono::time_point` or `std::chrono::duration` from `<chrono>`. This is a new C++11 header supported in GCC (from 4.6 I believe) and Microsoft Visual C++ (from 11.0); and, the bulk of this proposal came from [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/chrono.html).

Some examples:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

// Getting the current time (there is also high_resolution_clock available)
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> now = 
    std::chrono::system_clock::now();

// Do long time-consuming tasks, sleep for 10 seconds
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));

// Get time now
auto later = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

// Is now eariler than later ?
if (now < later)
{
    // Display difference between the two points of time
    auto x = later - now;

    std::cout 
        << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(x).count() 
        << " seconds" << std::endl
        << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(x).count() 
        << " milliseconds" << std::endl;
}
```

Hopefully it will work with what you are trying to do. If anything, look inside the `<chrono>` header and use it internally. It'll make you never want to look at any code using or pretending to use `<ctime>`.

Comment: Unfortunately using Visual Studio 2010 so don't have full c++11 support

Comment: Then I would refer you to the second paragraph of my answer. Boost contains a drop-in replacement for your use (until such time that you decide to upgrade your compiler) [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/chrono.html).